# For Each Loop in Visual Basic: IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: .net, vb.net, indexoutofrangeexception

Why does the following code gives IndexOutOfRangeException in VB.Net:

```
    Dim intNum() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    Dim tot As Integer
    For Each n As Integer In intNum
        tot = tot + intNum(n)
    Next
    MsgBox(tot)
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it give such an exception?

Comment: what does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Are you sure this is Java?

Comment: This is (most likely) VB.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean `VB.NET`, array indices range from 0 to the array upper bound of 4 which you exceed at the last index. If you wish to sum the elements you could do

```
For Each n As Integer In intNum
    tot = tot + n
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use some in-built functions.

```
Dim intNum() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Dim total = intNum.Sum()
```

Comment: You probably wouldn't believe how many guy's don't use extension's; good ole' Linq extention to the rescue.

Comment: I do too. The only issue I ever run into is when one of the other engineer's get's p!ssed off because it's confusing or long to read. But this is also coming from the one's that do not use it. It can be powerful when you need it...